# How to get current test fixture attribute

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I run selenium tests, and I have created a custom Test Fixture attribute that I apply to each fixture 3 times, each time with a new driver so my tests can run 3 separate times in 3 separate browsers. It looks like this:

```
[TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
class Edit<TWebDriver> : BaseTest<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
{
   [Test]
   public void Test()
   {
      //test code
   }
}
```

For my test fixtures, I mirror the web applications views in a 1:1 ratio - so the Dashboard\Index view in the web app code would be the Dashboard\Index folder for my tests that test the same view, therefore the test organization is very strict.

I am running into an issue that there are certain tests that should not run in certain browsers, such as IE. The majority of the tests need to however. What I am trying to do is for each test fixture

Is there any way to get the Test Fixture typeof value at test run time so I can do the following (pseudo code)...:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
   if(testFixture typeof is InternetExplorerDriver)
   {
      Assert.Ignore("test not to be run in IE");
   }

   // all the test code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the code modified below.

```
[TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
class Edit<TWebDriver> : BaseTest<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
{
    private TWebDriver webDriver;

    public Edit(TWebDriver webDriver)
    {
        this.webDriver = webDriver;
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        //test code
        if (this.webDriver.GetType() == typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))
        {
            Assert.Ignore("test not to be run in IE");
        }
    }
}
```